# Apache Caching within different VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, caching, virtualhost

I have two virtual hosts within my apache config, one for live and one for preview. In the moment there is no setting about cache and for all live customers, this is fine. But the preview customer with a lot of changes have some cache problems within the last weeks. I am not sure if this is an IE problem or not - anyway, I would like to disable cache for preview like mentioned in http://dabase.com/e/04038/ - but I would like to keep the cache for live customers. Both (preview and live) are using the same directories so I think I cannot use the .htaccess for this purpose?

Do you have any idea how I could realize this?

BTW, is there also a way to say: pls cache .swf files in preview and live? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) states, the header directives can also be set on server, vhost and directory.

In this case add the necessary directives to your respective vhost conf.